# liquibase doesn't insert <databaseChangeLog>

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, liquibase

I have next **pom.xml**:

```
<groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
<artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <id>test-databse-backup</id>
        <configuration>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db</url>
                <username>usr</username>
                <password>pswd</password>
                <outputChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db.changelog-databasestructure.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>generateChangeLog</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    ...................
```

So I make database backup by this maven plugin but in result file (`db.changelog-databasestructure.xml`) I don't see `<databaseChangeLog>` tag. How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your file `src/main/resources/db.changelog-databasestructure.xml` shouldn't already exist, So the plugin will create it and insert the `databaseChangeLog` XML element.

Otherwise, if you would keep your file exist before running the plugin, you have to insert it manually in your XML file.

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Maybe this is a bug.